# setTimeout to addClass, then check if element hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not able to console.log the message below. Does hasClass not work after setTimeout is used to addClass?

```
<img id="swipeUp1" class="swipeUp" src="img/arrow.png">

setTimeout(function() {
    $("#swipeUp1").addClass("moveOn");
}, 500);
if ($('#swipeUp1').hasClass('moveOn')) {
    console.log("swipeup1 has class moveOn");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setTimeout()` handler (the function containing the `addClass()`) is executed after the `if` statement, because you request explicitly to NOT execute it right now but in 500 milliseconds.

So the next line (the `if` statement) is executed immediately, long before the `addClass()`.

If you want them to be executed in order, you must move the `hasClass()` INSIDE the handler or the `addClass()` OUTSIDE:

```
// all inside handler
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#swipeUp1").addClass("moveOn");

    if ($('#swipeUp1').hasClass('moveOn')) {
        console.log("swipeup1 has class moveOn");
    }
}, 500);
```

Or:

```
// no setTimeout at all
$("#swipeUp1").addClass("moveOn");

if ($('#swipeUp1').hasClass('moveOn')) {
    console.log("swipeup1 has class moveOn");
}
```

Comment: My problem is that when I swipe back to the slide, I have to wait the 500ms again, is there a way to organize it so there can just be a 1 time delay on `$("#swipeUp1").addClass("moveOn");`, and not a delay on `if ($('#swipeUp1').hasClass('moveOn'))`

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for but you may want to look into jQuery's `delay()` method. You can chain animations, pauses and functions in a chain without ever using setTimeout().

Comment: I succesfully did it by making two setTimeout functions. The first with `$("#swipeUp1").addClass("moveOn");` at 500ms, then the if statement with hasClass at 600ms. Thanks for your help!